# Jquery Mobile number input in radio selection

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button

I am working on a calculator.  I would like to put 5 number inputs in a radio selection and solve for a number based on the radio selection.  However, I am having a difficult time getting a number input to display correctly inside a radio selection.  I've tried using the `<span>` tag, and most recently the ui-grid (see code below).  I just can't get a good result.

```html
<input type="radio" name="solveforthis" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="radio-choice-1" class="ui-li-desc">  
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a">Field 1</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="number" id="val1" value="0.013" style="width:40px"   maxlength="6" /></div>
    </div>
  </label>
<input type="radio" name="solveforthis" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" />
  <label for="radio-choice-2" class="ui-li-desc" value>  
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a">Field 2</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="number" id="val1" value="0.013" style="width:40px"   maxlength="6" /></div>
    </div>
  </label>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work in a radio selection?  Is there a better approach I should consider?

Comment: why are you displaying the numbers like that instead of just displaying them as the radio buttons value??

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Radio Buttons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="myPage">
    <div data-role="content"
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend><b>Choose a number:</b></legend>
             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
             <label for="radio-choice-1">1</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-2">2</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-3">3</label>

             <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
             <label for="radio-choice-4">4</label>
       </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

see also [the doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/)

Comment: Not exactly.  I'm trying to place a number input next to a label, inside the radio selection.

Comment: I prepared this answer 10 months ago and got +0 reputation for doing that. Ok, no problem. At least @Serge Pashkevich got now +2 reputation for his minor edit of my answer.

Comment: I agree with u. It is a pity when you spend your time for an answer and get no appreciation back.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same question...

solution: http://jsfiddle.net/55jZM/

using: `input type="number"` instead input `type="password"`